# Issue with two instances of same module in python?

Tags: python

I have two modules as follows:

*Module A - moda.py*

```py
import modb

x = None

def printx():
    global x
    print(x)

def main():
    global x
    x = 42
    printx()
    modb.printx()
    printx()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Module B - modb.py*

```py
import moda

def printx():
    moda.printx()

print('modb imported')
```

When I run `python moda.py`, the output I get is:

```
modb imported
42
None
42
```

I don't understand why the second print (coming from modb.printx()) is None. I thought python modules behaved as singletons. What am I missing?

**Can someone please explain why the module imported in `modb` is not same as the original module `moda`?**

Comment: To add to the confusion, running it like this you get what you would have expected: `python -c "import moda; moda.main()"`, i.e. it apparently matters which module is launched as the "main" module.

Comment: @jmd_dk. Or `python -m moda`

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, that gives the same result as in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an `import` statement is encountered, the interpreter looks for a corresponding key in `sys.modules`. If a key is found, it is bound to the name you requested. If not, a new empty module object is createdplaced in `sys.modules`, , and then populated. The reason for doing it like that is exactly to avoid infinite loops with circular imports.

When you run a module, it is imported under the name `__main__`. You ca

Here is the sequence of events when you run `moda` as a script:

1. Start of load of `moda.py` as `sys.modules['__main__']`. At this point, this is just an empty namespace
2. `import modb` encountered in `moda.py`. New empty namespace created for `sys.modules['modb']`.
3. `import moda` encountered in `modb.py`. New empty namespace created for `sys.modules['moda']`. Notice that this is **not** the same object as `sys.modules['__main__']` in step 1.
4. `import modb` encountered in `moda.py`. Since `sys.modules['modb']` exists, it is bound to that name in `moda`
5. Since `moda.py` is currently being loaded under the name `moda`, it finishes populating its namespace *without* running the import guard.
6. `modb.py` finishes populating its namespace (from step 2.) and runs `print('modb loaded')`.
7. `__main__` defined in `moda.py` finishes populating its namespace (from step 1.) and runs the import guard.

Hopefully this helps you visualize what happens. You have three modules, not two, that were loaded, because `moda` is loaded under two different names, and as two entirely different module objects.

The import guard in `__main__` calls `__main__.main`, which does the following:

1. Set `__main__.x = 42` (`moda.x` is still `None`)
2. `__main__.printx` prints `__main__.x`, which is `42`
3. `modb.printx` calls `moda.printx`, which prints `moda.x`, which is `None`.
4. `__main__.printx` prints `__main__.x` again, which is still `42`.